# Control robot remotely with a joystick

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to control my robot remotely with a joystick. On a Jetson Nano I have running roscore and I'm able to connect from my desktop to the Jetson over WiFi. But when I plug in the joystick the Jetson doesn't see the Jostick outputs cause it looks to it's own USB ports.

Is there a way that I plug in the joystick into my destop en send the joystick outputs over WiFi to the Jetson so it can be processed too control my motors?

I'm using VMware with Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic on the Jetson Nano. With ROSSerial I send data to a Arduino which controls the motors.

EDIT:
I have tried to run the script on the VM when I run the script and joy_node on the VM I see with echo outputs from the joy_node. Als (for debugging) some print statements in the script. But the data that need to be published is not published. But the weird thing is like I wrote above it all works perfect when I connect the joystick to the Jetson Nano usb port.

```
import rospy
import math
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
from r2g2.msg import Control_State

# Global variables used for processing the input value from the joystick
Xvelocity = 0
Yvelocity = 0
Zvelocity = 0
Max_Velocity = 100                              # Max velocity in rpm

# Global variables which will be published for left and right motor speed
Left_Motor_Speed = 0
Right_Motor_Speed = 0
Rotation_Speed = 0

# Initialize control input node
rospy.init_node("control_input", anonymous=True)

# Callback funtion for the Control State of R2G2 depending on the value a different control will be accomplished
def control_state_callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("Current control state is: %d", data.control_state_value)
    print(data.control_state_value)

def joystick_callback(data):
# Get joystick values max scale from joystick is -1 to 1 for x, y and z axis
    axes = data.axes
    global Yvelocity                             # Y position joystick represents Forward and Backwards velocity
    global Xvelocity                             # X position joystick represents turn angle will be used for difference in motor speed
    #global Zvelocity                             # Z position joystick represents rotation around Bot axis
     #Zvelocity = axes[2] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value   
     Yvelocity = axes[1] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value
     Xvelocity = axes[0] * Max_Velocity           # Scale joystick value to rpm value   
     process_velocities(Xvelocity, Yvelocity)

def process_velocities(x_val, y_val):
# First check if x and y values are not equal to zero
    if x_val == 0:
        # If the X position of the joystick is 0 than the bot drives straight and not further computation has to be done
        # Therefore both motors run equal speed.
        Left_Motor_Speed = y_val
        Right_Motor_Speed = y_val
    else:
        hyp = math.sqrt(x_val**2 + y_val**2)                # Find the hypothenuse of the two vectors
        vel_factor = abs(y_val/hyp)                         # Compute the cosine and use it as a attenuation factor for one of the wheels
        if x_val > 0:                                       # If x pos joystick is > 0, R2G2 needs to move to left, left motor turns slower as right motor
            Left_Motor_Speed = vel_factor * y_val
            Right_Motor_Speed = y_val
        else:                                               # If x pos joystick is < 0, R2G2 needs to move to right, right motor turns slower as left motor
            Left_Motor_Speed = y_val
            Right_Motor_Speed = vel_factor * y_val    

    # Print values for troubleshooting
    print("Left speed: ")
    print(Left_Motor_Speed)
    print("Right speed: ")
    print(Right_Motor_Speed)

    # Publish the computed velocities for each motor
    left_vel_pub.publish(Left_Motor_Speed)
    right_vel_pub.publish(Right_Motor_Speed)

# Create subscriber to Joystick node 
def joystick_subscriber():
    rospy.Subscriber('joy', Joy, joystick_callback)
    rospy.spin()

# Create Velocity publishers
left_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/left_velocity", Float32, queue_size=5)
right_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/right_velocity", Float32, queue_size=5)
# rotation_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher("/rotation_velocity", Float32, queue_size=10 )

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.Subscriber("/control_state", Control_State, control_state_callback)
    joystick_subscriber()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418087/control-robot-remotely-with-a-joystick/) by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2023-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Timothée](https://answers.ros.org/users/148408/timoth%C3%A9e/) on 2023-08-04**:
Do you have a node converting joystick input to ROS message on your nano ? If so you might want to put it on your virtual machine and ROS will handle the communication over WiFi

**Comment by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on 2023-08-04**:
Would I do that by just copy it to the VM and than in the terminal do a rosrun f the particular node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has been solved by doing as suggested. The node for the control should be running on the desktop and not the Jetson Nano.

---

Originally posted by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) with karma: 11 on 2023-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0